# WinAPI vs WinShellApi

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed edit on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30341830), where editor was removing [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) tag with comment that question is not related to the "Win32 API", but is related to the "Win32 Shell API". To be exact, author was using `Shell_NotifyIconA` [function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicona).

[winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) tag:

> The Windows API (formerly called the Win32 API) is the core set of application programming interfaces available for the Microsoft Windows operating systems. This tag is for questions about developing native Windows applications using the Windows API.

On MSDN, [Windows Shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_shell/) is structualized under Win32 API and imho I consider it to be right tag/category for the question.

Should the [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) tag be used for "Win 32 shell API" category too? And/or should we consider creating a new tag for this sub-category?

---

On meta we have [question about tagging C++ on Windows / NT native functions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357806/how-to-tag-c-windows-questions), but it doesn't clearly answer this topic.

Comment: Tag usage aside, A [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30341830) like that, which _only_ removes a single tag is basically _"no improvement"_, and should likely be rejected as such.

Comment: @Cerbrus A strawman interpretation of that statement outright false. Tags can be blatantly inappropriate. An edit that removes `[python]` from a purely Java question is obviously fine.

Comment: Even then, when such a blatantly wrong tag is added to a question, there's usually more to edit. If there is, I'd reject the suggestion, as it doesn't fix enough.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well this helps nobody then and just wasted several people's time. For me, tags are sorta special in that they also control the amount of noise in other people's inboxes in a way, so I give them more weight than content edits. In fact if I agree I'd even do "improve edit" and then save without changes, to skip the queue. After all we even get an "edit tags" option at a certain point, and we _do_ use it to "just edit tags" even if there would be more to fix, because this solves the first most pressing problem even if there isn't enough time/knowledge to fix more. How do you see that?

Comment: Where did I say I wouldn't properly fix the post after rejecting an edit that was too minor?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, that argument is blatantly false. It's not true in terms of the MSDN classification, nor is it true in terms of the classification system used on Stack Overflow.

Our [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) tag is appropriate for *any* question related to the Windows/Win32 API, which would include the shell APIs.

Note that there is also a [windows-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-shell) tag, which one might argue should be used on the question as well. But it should not be used *instead* of [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi), because the latter is how you're going to get the question seen by the appropriate subject-matter experts.

As a bit of general advice: ignore anyone who has their user name suffixed with "– MSFT". These users are, in my experience, the least knowledgeable, both about the technology and also about how Stack Overflow is supposed to work. This is not an "official designation" conferred upon a user account either by Microsoft or Stack Overflow. It's just something the user added to their own name. Thus, it should not be taken to imply any endorsement or specific expertise.

Comment: RE "MSFT": Is that really just the Microsoft stock identifier they added to their name, or is it also an abbreviation of something supposedly meaningful?

Comment: Yes, "MSFT" is the stock ticker symbol for Microsoft on the NASDAQ. It implies nothing official. It's just something the user added to their own display name when they set it. I could equally well add " - genius" to the end of my user name; would you be convinced?

Comment: Of all the things you could add... That's a great way to see they have no idea what they're talking about o.O

Comment: (Looks like that user has a couple of identical suggestions)

Comment: I wonder if MSFT is a "hangover" from the old Microsoft forums, @Cerbrus , where Microsoft Employees used MSFT as a declaration they were a Microsoft Employee. According to this [cached page](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:piOlcHnY64kJ:https://forums.asp.net/t/1126847.aspx%3FWHAT%2BIS%2BAN%2BMSFT%2B) it wasn't well received some members of the community.  *Surprise.* Perhaps this person is someone that was part of that community, and is still a Microsoft Employee.

Comment: Speaking as an ex-Microsoft employee, "MSFT" is a pretty standard way for employees to abbreviate the name of the company (I was there when "M$" was a pretty standard to abbreviate it in a derogatory fashion).  On the support forums, "-MSFT" is (/was) supposed to indicate that the user is either an employee or a vendor employee (working for MSFT support) and that the answer is in someway more definitive.  I don't know if that is (/was) regulated or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Flydog57, it is *not* regulated, at least not here on Stack Overflow, and that is precisely the problem. It used to be quite standard on the MSDN forums, but it has no meaning here. The *legitimate* Microsoft employees that I know do not have the " - MSDN" suffix after their user names, and for the users who do have this suffix, I cannot confirm that they are actually Microsoft employees. There is no evidence or breadcrumbs that would back up that conclusion. Anyone can add anything they want to their usernames here (except diamonds, which do actually have meaning).

Comment: I'm surprised you weren't aware of this designation, Cody. However, it's true that there are many users with the suffix who don't seem to know what they're talking about, even if it's also true that there are users who are appropriately using it to indicate their employment with the company, and not all Microsoft employees do. I guess it's just a matter of which kind we've encountered the most.

Comment: I am definitely *aware* of it, @BoltClock, from the MSDN forums. However, I'm *also* aware that it's as good as meaningless on Stack Overflow, and, anecdotally, everyone I've seen with this designation on their user names on SO has either been... how should I say... *unaware* of either how Microsoft tools or Stack Overflow itself works. It is a marker of complete incompetence here, as best as I can tell. It is... not a good look for Microsoft if these *are*, in fact, their employees, so I'm giving the company the benefit of the doubt that these are *not* employees.

Comment: Yeah, there's too many MSFT folks (legit or not) who come in and dump MSDN docs for rep (although [some seem to get it right](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11850033/wendy-zang-msft))

Comment: @CodyGray Anyone can say they're a genius. But have you tried "- *certified* genius"?

Comment: @user253751 You mean "- certified genius ✅" - And yeah I noticed how MSFT people seem to misuse Stack Overflow, and some highly experienced (and non-SO-misusing) people like [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) don't have the MSFT thing in the name, so... I do wonder if there is some sort of "community engagement program" or whatever at Microsoft where people actually get _asked_ to answer stuff here.